# Gui for viewing Apache headers

Tags: apache-2.2

Is there any GUI for viewing Apache headers which are being served by a chain 
of Reverse Proxy Servers.
I have a cloud which uses a few Proxy Servers in between the client and actual server which has to serve the original request.
All servers are Unix Servers.

And if there is a problem which I do not get a clue to then to be able to post them here 
downloading and doing an ftp of those headers with all the logs ,
loging in each time to each proxy server and Opening the browser and exporting the 
X display to some remote server each time from the chain and then observing 
HTTP_RESPONSES and checking the request from each of those servers and then posting log with configuration and response takes at least 2-3 hours to type an email.

Is there a shorter way to do so?

Answer (score 4):

I use `curl` when in text mode with one of the `-i` (include headers in the output) or `-D <filename>` (saves the headers to a file) parameters.

There's also the [Live HTTP Headers](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/) extension to firefox that provides a real good way to see the headers. Or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) if you want an extension to check everything you can in webpages (AJAX request, sizes of requests, redirects, javascript errors, and a lot of other stuff).

Answer (score 1):

You can check headers by using an application like http://www.http-inspector.com, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a GUI application that does exactly what you want but if you drop the GUI idea you could use a ssh + some handy scripts that perform the requests that you need.

The tool `wget` has a parameter named `--save-headers` so that wget saves both the body of the http response and the headers. From here on you can  use  favorite scripting language to extract the relevant headers, parse them, process them, etc.

The nice thing about the scripts is that once you've written them you can execute them over and over again speeding the debug process considerably.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Firefox, the [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/) extension has the ability to show you the response headers.

Comment: Hi as some one mentioned above you can write your scripts for Apache headers can you share with me any of such scripts.
I am learning to write scripts and this will help me and many others who might come across this question.

Answer (score 0):

The better resource is no doubt http://redbot.org/